# ngModelController: update view value after parser executed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
 myDirectives.directive('simpleDate', function ($filter, $locale, $timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var dateFormat = 'shortDate';

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                if (!modelValue) {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    return $filter('date')(modelValue, dateFormat);
                }
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                if (!isNaN(viewValue)) {
                    var now = new Date(),
                        year = now.getFullYear(),
                        month = now.getMonth() + 1,
                        day = Number(viewValue),
                        lastDay = (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();
                    if (day >= 1 && day <= lastDay) {
                        return '' + year + (month < 10 ? '-0' : '-') + 
                            month + (day < 10 ? '-0' : '-') + day;
                    }
                }

                return '';
            });
        }
    };     
 });
```

Parser calculates model value, and needs to reflect back view value; but how? I know there is ctrl.$render() method, but I guess it must run after $parser executed. The following didn't work:

```
$timeout(function () { ctrl.$render(); });
```

How can I render view value then?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect? :

```
 myDirectives.directive('simpleDate', function ($filter, $locale, $timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var dateFormat = 'shortDate';

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                if (!modelValue) {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    return $filter('date')(modelValue, dateFormat);
                }
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                if (!isNaN(viewValue)) {
                    var now = new Date(),
                        year = now.getFullYear(),
                        month = now.getMonth() + 1,
                        day = Number(viewValue),
                        lastDay = (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();
                    if (day >= 1 && day <= lastDay) {
                        var currentValue = '' + year + (month < 10 ? '-0' : '-') + month + (day < 10 ? '-0' : '-') + day;
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(currentValue);
                        ctrl.$render();
                        return currentValue;
                    }
                }

                return '';
            });
        }
    };     
 });
```